# items held back from updates

Tags: command-line, upgrade

The following packages have been kept back:

```
  libavcodec57 libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libinput10 libwayland-egl1-mesa libxatracker2 mesa-vdpau-drivers x265
  xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04
```

Comment: well these items or I believe the same list of items were shown on the previous upgrade as well.  This was just yesterday.  In the past I have been able to do these 'held-back' items using Synaptic.  Is this good procedure?

Comment: What happens if you run a `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: It appears that these items will be added so I will do that as Terrance suggested.  Also says I should use autoremove for several unneeded items so good coverage there too.

Comment: You can do that too.